# Spacing between the cells as per the label width in horizontal CollectionView in case of 2 rows

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewflowlayout

[image: The Final Design which is required] As shown above,I want **two fixed horizontal rows, with labels width according text and spacing  between  cells same as I’m getting in a single row**.
(Please refer  [Image Url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jopou.png))

I’m unable to achieve the same in case of two horizontal rows.
I used CollectionView for doing it, but no luck.

```
var dataArray = ["1A-Label", "2B-Label here", "3Chhhh", "4D-Label here", "5E-La here*","6F-Label here B-Label", "7G-Label", "8H-Label here", "9I- here", "10J-Label here", "11K-Label here------", "12L-Label here", "13M-Label here", "14N-Label here", "15O-Label here", "16P-Label here", "17Q-Label here------", "18R-Label here", "19S-Label here"]

let headerIdentifier = "HeaderView"
let headerName = "FilterCustomCollectionReusableView"
let brandCellIdentifier = "brandFilterCell"
let brandCellName = "BrandFilterCollectionViewCell"

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    baseCollectionView.register(UINib(nibName: headerName, bundle: nil), forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: headerIdentifier)
    baseCollectionView.register(UINib(nibName: brandCellName, bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: brandCellIdentifier)
    baseCollectionView.delegate = self
    baseCollectionView.dataSource = self
    collectionViewHeight.constant = 90

    if let flowLayout = self.baseCollectionView?.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
        flowLayout.estimatedItemSize = CGSize(width: 1, height: 1)
    }
}

//MARK:- Collection Functions
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return dataArray.count
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: brandCellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! BrandFilterCollectionViewCell
        cell.configureBrandCell(labelText: dataArray[indexPath.row])
        return cell
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
    switch kind {
    case UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader:
        let headerView = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: headerIdentifier, for: indexPath)
        return headerView
    default:
        assert(false, "Unexpected element kind")
    }
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: 100, height: baseCollectionView.frame.height)
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.
**Thanks in advance for the help.**

Comment: could you have a final UI design to show?not quite understand what you want

Comment: @CharlieCai I have edited the question and added the final UI design. Please find the same.

Comment: suggest using the waterfall layout  https://github.com/ecerney/CollectionViewWaterfallLayout and make scrollDirection horizontal " layout.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal"

Comment: @CharlieCai I tried the same but still it's not working.

Comment: after some research,I believe you can inherit UICollectionFlowLayout, and  mimic how those libraries implement watchfall layout.func layoutAttributesForElements and collectionViewContentSize is what you are looking for